# replaceAll regular expression Replacing $

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to replace all $ characters in a String expression like this

an example of a string with s$ and another with $s and here is the end.

so that the $ characters are surrounded by spaces.

I've tried  `string.replaceAll("$", " $ ");` 
This results in a illegal Argument Exception.

When I try escaping the $ character like this:

```
string.replaceAll("\$", " $ ");  I get an invalid escape sequence error before I even build.
```

When I try the following:

```
string.replaceAll("\\$", " $ ");  I get an illegal argument exception again.
```

Finally when I try this:

```
string.replaceAll("\\\\$", " $ ");
```

It has no effect on the string at all.    I know this is something stupid that I'm just not getting.    Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need two slashes on both sides

```
string.replaceAll("\\$", " \\$ ");
```

The first one escapes the second slash that will be passed to the regular expression. The expression is then "\$" which matches the $ sign. And you want to replace it with the same.

You have to escape the second parameter as well because allthough its not a regular expression the \ and the $ sign are a specical case here according to the documentation:

> Note that backslashes () and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceAll. Use Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String) to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired.

Comment: It was the need to escape the second $ sign that was messing me up.   I just saw that it was a string and assumed that $ had no special meaning as such.    Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need parameters to be treated as regexps, use `replace()` instead of `replaceAll()` (it replaces all occurences of the first parameter as well, but doesn't treat it as regexp):

```
string.replace("$", " $ ");
```

Comment: This is the best solution. No need to use regular expressions in this case! +1

Answer (score 0):

Try `string.replaceAll("\\$", " \\$ ")`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you have to esacpe the $ sign in the replacement string is because the String#replaceAll() method uses Matcher#replaceAll() underneath the hood. Straight from the latter's Javadoc:

> Note that backslashes (\) and
>   dollar signs ($) in the
>   replacement string may cause the
>   results to be different than if it
>   were being treated as a literal
>   replacement string. Dollar signs may
>   be treated as references to captured
>   subsequences as described above, and
>   backslashes are used to escape literal
>   characters in the replacement string.